# Downloading a dynamically created text file from Java, write directly to computer or save on server?

Tags: java, file-writing

When a user clicks a download button (coded in simple Javascript) on my webpage, it triggers a PHP function that calls to a java file. This Java code connects to the database and writes to a text file.

Currently, the code is in development on my local machine. Here is a snippet of the code is currently creating a local text file and writing the information to it:

```
        StreamFactory sf = StreamFactory.newInstance();
        sf.loadResource("mapping.xml");
        File file = new File("C:\\MyLocal\\foo.txt");
        BeanWriter bw = sf.createWriter("fileExport", file);

        // writes beans
        bw.write("", "");
        ...

        bw.flush(); // flushes to foo.txt located in C:\MyLocal
```

**My question is is it possible to write this dynamically created text file to the user's computer instead of my local, and if so, is it a good web development practice?** The benefit this way is that I don't need to store foo.txt on the server that the code will reside. However, I'm not very familiar with web development practices, and did not see a concrete rule on this subject matter.

If it is better to save it to the server and then implement some download code from there, **should this be handled within the PHP of the page or the Java backend functions**?

Comment: You can write directly to stdout and make php read it. But the question is: Why would you do this with php+java when you can do everything with php?

Comment: This is currently done in Java because of preexisting objects being used. Basically, the java code creates a "form" object with various "section" objects. Since the form is quite large and includes many objects, it'd be a pain recreating this in PHP.
That and I'm not very experienced with PHP and much more experienced with Java :-)

Comment: How would your server know how to reach the users computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to write on user's computer filesystem.

Because of javascript security measures, if it wasn't because of this, a malicious website/webapp could write a huge amount of data on users hard drive, or could write malicious scripts.

The option a user has it's to download a file, but a webpage doesn't have direct access to user filesystem.

There was a proposal API for doing something like this, but it was discontinued
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answering to your question: definitely **it's not a good practice** to try to write files on users filesystem

**You should handle the download with Java on the Backend**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! With regards to the "handling the download with Java on the Backend," is it right to take this as "have the file save to somewhere on the server within the Java code (basically as it's already written), then use some javascript/php function to target that file and download it, correct? Since I can't imagine that the java code itself could "download" onto the client's filesystem, correct?

Comment: You can send almost any file on your server to the user, 
Take a look at this example
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/
Look at steps 1 and 2, you will have enough with that to send your file on your servlet to the user (if you're using servlets)

Comment: The other option is to place your file on a public folder on your server (/www) and provide the user with the url/anchor tag that points to that file